# Absolute positioned div inside of block with position:fixed and scrollbars

Tags: css, scroll, css-position

I have a div with `position: fixed`, which contains two other divs inside: one with content and second which must always be positioned on the bottom of the main div.

Here is an example:

```css
.scroller {
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
  <div class="content">
    <div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div>
    <div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div>
    <div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that footer starts to move with other content when user scrolls content of the main block, despite of position:absolute of the footer block.

Is there any way to stick footer to the bottom of the main fixed block without changing html structure?

And what if main div contains many children and only last of them is the footer which we need to stick to bottom? Example:

```css
.scroller {
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
  <div class="content">
    <div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: BTW, you might run into a problem "if" you decide to add `width:100%` to your `.footer`, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/unV9H/8/ (building on top of Oriol's solution), as the lower part of your scrollbar will be hidden by your `.footer`.

Answer (score 6):

Since the absolutely positioned element is inside `.scroller` and you don't want it to move when scrolling, the scrollable container should be `.content` instead to `.scroller`.

```css
.content {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Moreover, you should remove `bottom: 0` from the fixed wrapper so that its height is given by its content, that is, `100px`.

```css
.scroller {
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 240px;
}
.content {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
  <div class="content">
    <div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div>
    <div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div>
    <div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

In case you want multiple `.content` elements and don't want to scroll each one separately, you can wrap them all in a `.scroller-inner` container, and set the styles above to it.

```css
.scroller {
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 240px;
}
.scroller-inner {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
  <div class="scroller-inner">
    <div class="content">
      <div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you know the height of the header, you can make the footer a fixed element, and use margins to correct its position. This is kinda hacky, though.

```css
.scroller {
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100px; /* val1 */
  top: 0; /* val2 */
  overflow: auto;
}
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  white-space: nowrap;
  top: 100px; /* val1 + val2 */
  line-height: 20px; /* val3 */
  font-size: 16px; /* val4 */
  margin-top: -18px; /* val3/2 + val4/2 */
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
  <div class="content">
    <div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like it except for the fact that you have to specify the height of the container... +1

Comment: Oddly enough, but the scrollbar will disappear in Chrome. For me at least.

Comment: @ChrisHarris2012 Fixed, now it doesn't specify the height of the container.

Comment: @snuffn That's weird, both http://jsfiddle.net/unV9H/3/ and http://jsfiddle.net/unV9H/9/ work well on Chrome for me... (I have Chrome 21.0.1180.75 m)

Comment: This is also a nice workaround when fixed positioning is called for, but won't work, especially on mobile devices. Thanks!